# Volley Request And Spinner

Tags: android, request, spinner, android-volley

I have an assync request using GsonRequest and Volley to get my list of objects and i have a spinner that it's populated into that request.

I want to set a selection after my spinner is populated into the request, but i need to make it out of my volley request.

This is my response...

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Estado[] response) {
            ArrayList<Estado> estadoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            Estado estado = new Estado();
            estado.setId(0);
            estado.setDescricao("Selecione um estado");

            estadoArrayList.add(estado);
            estadoArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(response));

            estadoAdapter = new EstadoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, estadoArrayList);
            spn_estado.setAdapter(estadoAdapter);

//I dont want to setselection here
//If i do the selection here, it work like a charm.
//spn_estado.setSelection(usuario.getEndereco().getCidade().getEstado().getId(), false);

            progressDialogEstado.dismiss();
        }
```

In this method, i call my request and i want to set selection HERE...

```
private void veferyUser() {

progressDialogEstado = Util.ProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Carregando Estados", getString(R.string.prompt_aguarde));

//This requestEstados() call my GsonRequest to enter into the code above.
            requestEstados();

spn_estado.setSelection(usuario.getEndereco().getCidade().getEstado().getId(), false);
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how can i populate my spn_estado (Spinner)... Because my request it's assync.. It call my request and after that call the spn_estado... and it comes null the adapter because its assync...